# CSS3 Transition Ease in and out Box Shadow

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

I am trying to get div id to ease in and out of a box shadow using CSS3.

The current CSS I have is:

```css
#how-to-content-wrap-first:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #1e1e1e; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #1e1e1e; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #1e1e1e;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

The issue I am having is that on the first hover of the element there is no easing in or out and then any subsequent hovers ease in but do not ease out.

Any advice people have would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to use transitions on `.class` and not `.class:hover`

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #515151;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: needed to be `box-shadow: none` for me in the div.

Comment: There is a better (= performance optimized) way to animate box-shadow. See http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [resource-efficient solution](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/)

```css
#how-to-content-wrap-first::after{
    /* Pre-render the bigger shadow, but hide it */
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px -1px #80aaaa;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;         
}

#how-to-content-wrap-first:hover::after {
    /* Transition to showing the bigger shadow on hover */
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This could work:

```
 #how-to-content-wrap-first:hover{
      box-shadow : inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
      -webkit-transition : box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
      transition : box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
 }
```